# Android - NullPointerException using ViewGroup

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, viewgroup

When I relocate from one Activity to another using just simple TextView - it works.
piece of code:

```
 private RMProject currentProject;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.open_proj);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    currentProject = bundle.getParcelable("current");
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label_open_project);
    textView.setText("Project "+currentProject.getName());

}
```

But when I use another activity with the next code in **onCreate()** method - it doesn't work and I receive NullPointerException. In line #38. I checked, I received textView when used first piece of code.

```
public class EventsActivity extends Activity {
private RMProject currentProject;
private ListView listView;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    EventDBManager.init(this);
    ViewGroup contentView = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.orm_event_list, null);
    listView = (ListView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.ormListView);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    currentProject = bundle.getParcelable("current");
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ormTextView);
    //38 line - next, which cause exception
    textView.setText("Project "+currentProject.getName());
    Button btn = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.ormButtonAdd);
    setupButton(btn);
    setContentView(contentView);
}
}
```

I guess that issue with the components layout.
Here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:editable="true"
        android:text="Project name"
        android:id="@+id/ormTextView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>
<Button
        android:id="@+id/ormButtonAdd"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add " />
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/ormListView"
        android:layout_above="@id/ormButtonAdd"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And exception that I've been received:

> 04-15 18:26:29.209    1401-1401/nikolay.rm E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: nikolay.rm, PID: 1401
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{nikolay.rm/nikolay.rm.activities.EventsActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>               at nikolay.rm.activities.EventsActivity.onCreate(EventsActivity.java:38)**
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)

Comment: It should be `TextView textView = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.ormTextView);` But why don't you simply call `setContentView(R.layout.orm_event_list);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your missing contentView reference in the following line

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ormTextView);
```

So fix would be to replace it with

```
TextView textView = (TextView) contentView .findViewById(R.id.ormTextView);
```

Hope this helps